# Serializing a JSON object to send via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some data in a JSobject via AJAX using jQuery.

Here's the json object.

```
var cookieData = {
        'land' : document.URL,
        'ref' : document.referrer
    };
```

The object is them stored in a cookie... via `JSON.stringify(cookieData);`

Before the form is sent and AJAX post is made, I need to get the object's properties:

```
var cookieData = cookie.get(website); //return the cookieData in stringified form.
var submitData = 'tracking=' +cookieData + jQuery("#quoteForm").serialize();
```

However, on the receiving application's end, the data is unusable, is there any way that I can serialize it for use in an AJAX post?

The receiving end is a PHP application, processed with:

```
$trackingData = json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['tracking']),true);
```

Comment: your object has an extra comma, fyi. Also, it's just a javascript object, not a json object. what do you mean by the data is unusable? did you forget the `&` between your json data and the serialized data? It would be easier to pass this data as an object rather than a string, let jQuery turn it into a param string.

Comment: It would be of much help, if you posted the receiving PHP application code :)

Comment: @KevinB Friday afternoons destroy me... You are correct

Comment: @tomahaug posted the relevant PHP bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be that the problem is a missing &, try this

```
var submitData = 'tracking=' + cookieData + '&' + jQuery("#quoteForm").serialize();
```

By the way, which error return php or the json_decode/whatever you use to decode the json?

Comment: The $_REQUEST looks like that the tracking key contains both the cookieData and the serialized form data ?

Comment: @Shamil Exactly. That is probably the issue. Try adding the '&' in the query as daniele_dll suggests :)

Comment: @tomahaug it's happened with that in there... let me hard refresh the JS